# Issue with socket.io-stream during install

Tags: angular, socket.io

Im trying to implement the package `socket.io-stream` in my Angular project, but after I import it, when I start the project I have this error :

```
index.js:13 Uncaught ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined
    at 5421 (index.js:13:15)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
    at 841 (index.js:2:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
    at 325 (user-connection.service.ts:9:21)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
    at 3010 (contact.component.html:125:125)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
    at 158 (main.js:15:98)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
```

I have installed the buffer package using `npm i buffer` nothing changed.

Comment: Could you join [this chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246144/chat-with-soup3eee) ?

Comment: Hi, I just saw your message but I don't have enough reputation to awnser. This is what I needed thank you my friend. Also I have an other question can we speak on discord if you want to? soup3ee#9053

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an Angular wrapper for the library called `ngx-socket-io`

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-socket-io

Good tutorial on getting it up and running

- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-socket-io